# problem redirection on product page when using http protocol

Tags: magento-1, url-rewrite, magento-1.6, product-urls, redirect-url

I got a problem in magento 1.6

In production environment, I pass a product url using http, it will be converted to https://domain/catalog/product/view/id/18341/category/451 instead of https://domain/producturlrewrite that ends with .html

I have the same configuration in dev environnement and it works like a charm

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please run url_rewrite indexer from your admin

Comment: I already done that but it doesnt seem to work, I cleared cash as well, thanks